# NSTokenField click completion list item

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, rubymotion

I have an `NSTokenField` in my application and I implemented the `tokenField:completionsForSubstring:indexOfToken:indexOfSelectedItem:` method in which I specify the receiver’s tokenizing character set with the `setTokenizingCharacterSet:` method:

```rb
  def tokenField(tokenField, completionsForSubstring:substring, indexOfToken:tokenIndex, indexOfSelectedItem:selectedIndex)
    tokenField.setTokenizingCharacterSet(NSCharacterSet.whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet)
  end
```

It works as expected when I click on the space bar or the enter button. I would also like to have the same behavior when I click on one of the item of the completion list with my mouse.

How is that possible?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know if it's possible to have this behaviour with a NSTokenField.

But you should take a look at [MTTokenField](https://github.com/smorr/MTTokenField) which do what you want out of the box.

To do so, you will have to:

1.Create an Xcode Project as a Static Library(Do not enable ARC).

2.Save your project to vendor/MTTokenField

3.Drag and drop all the files of MTTokenField located in the subdirectory 'MTTokenField' to your new XCode project. Choose to copy the files.

4.Add this to your rakefile in order to compile and link the library with your Rubymotion project.

```
app.vendor_project("vendor/MTTokenField/", :xcode, :xcodeproj => "MTTokenField.xcodeproj", :target => "MTTokenField", :products => ["libMTTokenField.a"], :headers_dir => "MTTokenField")
```

5.In Interface Builder change the class of your NSTokenField to NSTextField and then set its custom class to MTTokenField, and also change the custom class of the cell: MTTokenFieldCell instead of NSTextFieldCell.

6.Then you have to set the delegate of your MTTokenField to a class which has to respond to :

```
def tokenField(tokenField, completionsForSubstring: substring )
   # your have to return an array containing your results matching substring.
end
```

And that's it. It should work.

Hope it helps !

Answer (score 2):

I found another solution using `NSTokenField` instead of `MTTokenField`.

In the delegate of my NSTokenField, I used the controlTextDidChange method of NSControl which is called anytime I write a character in my token field. In this method I check if there is a NSLeftMouseUp event which is triggered, and if it's the case, I simulate a click on Return. And that's it.

```
def controlTextDidChange(aNotification)
  application = NSApplication.sharedApplication
  event = application.currentEvent
  if event.type == NSLeftMouseUp
    e1 = CGEventCreateKeyboardEvent(nil, 0x24, true)
    CGEventPost(KCGSessionEventTap, e1)
  end
end
```

There is one more thing to do to make it properly work: the issue here is that if I have a completion list with 3 items for instance, one of them will be selected by default, let's say the first one. In this case, the solution will work as expected if I click the second or the third item but I will have to double click the first item to make it work.

To fix this, turn off the autocompletion and only display the suggestion box, i.e add this line to the tokenField:completionsForSubstring:indexOfToken:indexOfSelectedItem: method:

```
selectedIndex[0] = -1
```

Comment: Any idea how to do this in Swift?